# Why can I play media files as they are downloading on Linux, but not Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, filesystems, ntfs, ext4

On Linux (with ext4) I can open a video file for playback as it is being downloaded via another program (my browser, wget, a torrent client with sequential downloading enabled, etc). My media player will happily play it back for me without any hiccups, so long as the file streams in faster than I can play it back. On the other hand, Windows pretty much won't let you do anything with a file while another program is writing to it. What about ext4 makes this possible that isn't present on filesystems like NTFS?

Comment: What is your Windows setup? At one point I recall I had a video file downloading in CyberFox in PM and I was able to play the file in vlc.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much about "features" of ext4 or any other Linux filesystem that makes it possible, it's about the defaults when opening files using application programmer's interface (API) on each platform.

On Windows, [CreateFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) without further options prevents any other processes from opening it at the same time. You have to explicitely specify a `FILE_SHARE` option if you want to allow other processes to do so.

On Linux, creating a file with [fopen](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen) using mode `w` or `w+` allows all other processes to read and write it. You have to explicetely use other system calls like `flock` to prevent that.

That's the reason why a newly created file (by your browser, `wget` etc.) can be read by default on Linux, while it is not shared by default on Windows. In principle, if the programmers had wanted, they could also do it the other way round. But that would require additional effort.